# How do i change the size of a CheckBox Title or make it Wrap in a PreferenceScreen xml?

Tags: android, xml, checkbox, title, android-preferences

I'm writing a preference screen in in xml for my Android application. My issue is that some of the titles of the preferences are too long and will not wrap the page. Consider my example:

```
 <CheckBoxPreference
                android:title="Language Detection (BETA)"
                android:defaultValue="false"
                android:summary="Automatically decide which language to use"
                android:key="lan_det_pref"
                android:textSize="15px"
                android:lines="4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                />
```

Maybe I'm missing something but I have tried using number of other properties with no positive results. I have tried android:singleLine, android:lines, etc., and none of these seem to effect the title of the preference. Also is there a way to scale down the size of a CheckBox title?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A CheckBoxPreference is not derived from View, so the usual view attributes don't apply.

Instead, a CheckBoxPreference is bound to a view, which has a predefined layout.

You can derive a class from CheckBoxPreference and override onBindView. In your class' onBindView, find the CheckBox view and adjust its view attributes to your liking.

```
class MyCBPref extends CheckBoxPreference{
  public MyCBPref( Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
  }
  protected void onBindView( View view){
    super.onBindView(view);
    makeMultiline(view); 
  }
  protected void makeMultiline( View view)
  {
    if ( view instanceof ViewGroup){

        ViewGroup grp=(ViewGroup)view;

        for ( int index = 0; index < grp.getChildCount(); index++)
        {
            makeMultiline(grp.getChildAt(index));
        }
    } else if (view instanceof TextView){
        TextView t = (TextView)view;
        t.setSingleLine(false); 
        t.setEllipsize(null);
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your layout, reference your class instead of CheckBoxPreference:

```
<com.mycorp.packagename.MyCBPref android:title="..." ... />
```

Comment: i donot get the result,i also get one line

Comment: sorry, my memory was serving me slightly wrong. Edits in place. Look for the TextViews (not CheckBox) and simply switch off the single line flag and set Ellipsize to null. If you only want to apply this for the title and not the summary, also insert a "break;" since the header comes first. It should be noted that this is sort of a hack as it may be rendered ineffective should the Android framework change the layout of the checkbox preferences in a future release. However, it will always make all textviews in the Checkbox preference show all text that was provided which should usually be ok.

Comment: i aslo cannot get the result.

Comment: android:title="this is two \n\n line1"
                android:summary="toggle_preference"

Comment: sorry, my fault - need to add recursion since there is one more layer of layouts around. Edits above.

Answer (score 2):

You could customize you checkbox like this:
MyPreference.xml

```
<CheckBoxPreference android:key="testcheckbox" 
    android:title="Checkbox Title" 
    android:summary="Checkbox Summary..." 
    android:layout="@layout/custom_checkbox_preference_layout">
</CheckBoxPreference>
```

and custom_checkbox_preference_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dip"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+android:id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

        <TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
            android:maxLines="4" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the point is android:singleLine="false"".

Answer (score 0):

You can derive a class from `CheckBoxPreference` and override `onBindView`. In your class `onBindView`, find the `CheckBox` view and adjust its view attributes to yours.

Comment: How does copying a paragraph with slight modifications from [@Thorstenw's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4268968/101361) provide additional value to this question?